# Flask Update paths upon deployment

Tags: flask, routes, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I've been developing a flask app using the development server. Now that I'm ready to deploy it to another machine (which already has a bunch of other stuff on it), I'm learning about how to use mod_wsgi to hook into apache (which is already running on the server.) I would like my entire flask app to sit under a path like `/mysite`. I know that I can use `WSGIScriptAlias` to denote a prefix and to send flask everything after this prefixed path.

This works well for making all routes behave as expected, but **what about my HTML/css/javascript files?** If I refer to a path in an HTML file, do I have to change that? Or is there some way of fixing this more globally?

I worry that I might be in for a lot of rewriting...

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: In case anyone's wondering...I just did all the rewriting. It was a relatively small app, so it wasn't the worst. I'm still curious about finding a better way, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blueprints allow you to structure your application in a very modular fashion, but also have the benefit of declaring a specific url prefix for each set of routes. This is very handy in a large application because you can specify your route paths *relatively*, and instead of having to update *all of your routes if your url structure changes, you simply update the prefix for that blueprint*. I am simplifying a bit, but you can read more about this pattern of structuring applications [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/)

The real benefit of Blueprints for *smaller* applications is that if you only have a single Blueprint object associated with your app, you can simply declare the url prefix for that Blueprint and it will apply the prefix to every route in your app!

Here is a very simple example demonstrating this concept

`File structure`

```
.
├── app.py
└── static
    └── index.js
```

`index.js`

```js
console.log('hello from static!');
```

`app.py`

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, jsonify, url_for
# there are a million ways to handle configuration,
# this is just for simplicity's sake for this example.
configuration = dict(
    development = dict(
        ENV='development',
        APPLICATION_ROOT='/',
    ),
    production=dict(
        ENV='production',
        APPLICATION_ROOT='/mysite/',
    ),
)
# get configuration based on environment
config_key = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG', 'development')
config_dict = configuration[config_key]
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path=config_dict['APPLICATION_ROOT'])
app.config.update(config_dict)
bp = Blueprint('myapp', __name__)

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify(message='hello from root!')

@bp.route('/foo')
def foo():
    path = url_for('static', filename='index.js')
    return jsonify(path=path)

# attach your routes to the application
app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix=app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The biggest changes from what you're probably used to seeing are
- we are using `@bp.route` instead of `@app.route`, this is so that our paths can be automatically set relative to our url prefix
- we have to take an additional step `app.register_blueprint()` in order for Flask to be able to find our routes (without this, you would only get 404's)

When we run `python3 app.py` (or, `flask run`) and navigate to the regular root route `/`, we receive our message.

`localhost:5000`

```
{"message": "hello from root!"}
```

When we visit our `/foo` route, we get the following response back telling us where our javascript file is located

`localhost:5000/foo`

```
{"path":"/index.js"}
```

Navigating there, we do in fact see the contents of our file

`localhost:5000/index.js`

```js
console.log('hello from static!);
```

Previously, since we did not have an environment variable `FLASK_CONFIG` set, our app defaulted to using our *development* settings. Now let's see what happens when we set that value, like we would in production

```sh
$ export FLASK_CONFIG=production
```

Now, navigating to our previous root route returns a 404, so we instead go to our production url prefix

`localhost:5000/mysite`

```
{"message": "hello from root!"}
```

Navigating to our `/foo` route to see where our static file is located

`localhost:5000/mysite/foo`

```
{"path":"/mysite/index.js"}
```

And finally, navigating to that path does in fact display our javascript file

`localhost:5000/mysite/index.js`

```js
console.log('hello from static!);
```

If you'd prefer to prefix your static assets with something else as part of the url, perhaps even just `/static/<your-file>`, all you have to do is change this line in `app.py`

```py
# from this
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path=config_dict['APPLICATION_ROOT'])

# to this
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path=config_dict['APPLICATION_ROOT']+'static/')
```

now your paths will look like `localhost:5000/static/index.js`, for example.

Finally, to address your concern about having to change your paths in HTML files: you can use the same `url_for()` function as is demonstrated in the `foo` route to refer to anywhere in your blueprint. The trick is to refer to the *route's function name*, so if you wanted to create a link to `foo()` you would use `url_for('bp.foo')`, where `'bp'` is the string used in the `Blueprint` function.

I know that's a lot of information, but this concept was difficult for me to understand when I was first learning so I'm trying to help save someone else from headache. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Very comprehensive. At the beginning of reading I didn't think it was going to answer my question, but by the end I saw how it does. It's kind of tricky!